# Qgis2Web - nothing shows up

Tags: qgis2web

I have the latest Qgis2Web and am running Qgis 2.2.0 - I was able to run the plugin and the programme went through the motions resulting in "success" (message box) and the resulting "folder".

I saved it to my local folder and opened the "index" file on both my chrome/safari - both resulted in a blank screen.

Is there something I have done wrong or missed out?

Here are some screen shots: (enclosed)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are running QGIS 2.2 (ie that wasn't a typo), it's not supported by qgis2web.

Comment: It works nicely on 2.18 (thanks Tom Chadwin)